# Sass @mixin and @include compilation error

Tags: css, sass

Here's my scss file

```
@mixin important-text {
 color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.danger {
  @include: important-text;
  background-color: green;
}
```

After I compiled with koala I receive an error says -

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "  @include": expected identifier, was ": important-text;"
       on line 9 of C:\Users\
```

I have no idea where it did go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including a mixin the `:` is unnecessary and will cause an error.

Instead:

```
@mixin mixin-name() {...}

@include mixin-name();
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be`@include mixin_name`

```
danger {
 @include important-text;
 background-color: green;
}
```

[reference](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

Comment: I tried to changed to `@mixin important_text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.danger {
  @include: important_text;
  background-color: green;
}` but still the error is there when I compile.